# Blender Internal Animation Render Crashes with New Font

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, text-object

I realize this sounds dubious ... possibly a bug... probably user error.

When I add a new font to a blender project that came with pre-packaged font it causes the BI animation rendering to crash Blender.

The message in the upper left says, 'Frame 1 ... Raytree Building', then Blender exits with no further warning or error message.

[image: blender render error]

... on tinkering around a little more it's a specific true type font that I just imported ...

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it happen with any font or just specific ones?

Comment: A specific font, others are fine.

Comment: I got it to work, certain fonts are 'acceptable' in blender ... generally those with ligature, a connection between the letters, will not be supported.  I can answer my own question with a citation from blender.org along with a link to fonts that are acceptable.

Comment: @StephanLuis I reopened it answer away.

Comment: @StephanLuis please write an answer to your own question. Others with a similar problem might find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering My Own Question:**

Blender is short on official documentation ... [it appears](https://www.blendernation.com/2006/11/02/font-library/#comment-15593) that free type fonts are supported and of those Blender can be picky about fonts with ligatures, or connections between letters.

So far all the fonts from http://www.dafont.com, recommended on that site, that I have tried worked.  That said I've only tried 4 that were very close to the original.

With that information I've been able to BI render the animated title sequence.